# How do I preg_match this?

Tags: preg-match

I need help to write a preg_match to extract the 0.85 and 1.00 from this into php variables. Been trying all day with no success!

```
Chop Suey</a></td><td align="right">0.85</td><td align="right">1.00</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you 0.85 and 1.00 from your specified string, stored in `$values[1]` and `$values[2]` respectively.

```
$values = array();
preg_match('/Chop Suey<\/a><\/td><td align="right">([\d]+\.[\d]+)<\/td><td align="right">([\d]+\.[\d]+)<\/td>/', 'Chop Suey</a></td><td align="right">0.85</td><td align="right">1.00</td>', $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also be more dynamic with it. Instead of statically looking for "chop suey" why not look for other alignments.

Here is a sample to that. (very basic).

```
preg_match("/\d+.\d+/",$content,$output);
```

(above match, would give you all the decimals you need in correct order.)

```
$output[0] (is the array you can loop)

for the exact numbers above, you'd use $output[0][0] and $output[0][1]
```

as seen in the regex example [here](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=1301)